# Systemverilog: referencing to a register/variable with a string and changing its value

Tags: system-verilog

I have a sample of code of what I would like to do below

```
logic [3:0] c0_var, c1_var, c2_var, c3_var; 
string pref = "c1"

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    //Change the value of c1_var to 11
    pref + "_var" = 4'd11;
end
```

Is there a way to use strings to reference to a variable/logic/register so that I could change them? I'm not sure how well I am phrasing my question, but please do let me know if you need more clarification. Thank you!

Comment: I just want to change the value of any of those cn_var directly, without using cases and if-statements. It does not have to use string, I just would like to refer to the variables directly with a changing prefix.

Comment: Make an array instead: logic[3:0] var[3:0]; ... pref=1;

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that arrays are not possible in my use case; the wires are set with the prefixes. I understand what you mean though as I can take advantage of constructs such as generate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preprocessor can handle this case.

```
logic [3:0] c0_var, c1_var, c2_var, c3_var; 
`define PREF c1
`define ADD_VAR(VAR) VAR``_var

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
    //Change the value of c1_var to 11
    //pref + "_var" = 4'd11;
    `ADD_VAR(`PREF) = 4'd11;
end
```